# PYTHON 2.7 - Evaluating Both Values at Once in a 2-D Array

Tags: python-2.7, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
myarray = array([[Me, False], [Me, True], [Partner, False], [Me, True], [Me, False],[Me, True],[Partner, True]])
```

What I'm trying to do is to start a counter each time [Me, True] appears and have that counter increment until either [Partner, True] or [Partner, False] appears in the array. Each time this counter would encounter the [Me, True] and thus reset, I intend to add it to another variable just to keep a sum.

If total_counter = 0 and temp_counter = 0,

In the example above since [Me, True] appears right before [Partner, False], temp_counter would increment to 1, then get added to total_counter when [Partner, False] is encountered and reset to 0.

Now total_counter = 1 and temp_counter = 0

When [Me, True] appears next, temp_counter would reach 3 before encountering [Partner, True] and resetting to 0 and total_counter = 4.

I give you all this just to provide context but my issue is that in the start of my code:

```
for x,y in myarray:
    if x == "Me":
        print x,y
        temp_counter = temp_counter + 1

[Me, False]
[Me, True]
etc
```

That works just fine. But if I do

```
for x,y in myarray:
    if x == "Me" and y == "True":
       temp_counter = temp_counter + 1 
       print x,y
```

Seems to not trigger at all. Is there something about the way the for loop is evaluating this that makes it... only look at x for both "Me" and "True" or something? Any explanation would be greatly appreciate!

-Mano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if x == "Me" and y == "True":
```

Has quotes around `True` which must be removed.  In Python, a boolean and a string are not equivalent.